# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am going to delete the object by id but i am getting error like:

**com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydatabase`.`assignmentaudit`, CONSTRAINT `FKqgsllo6dm5kdx7ptc3qu5mefd` FOREIGN KEY (`auditor_group_id`) REFERENCES `auditor_group` (`auditor_group_id`))**

The method i made to delete by id is :

```
@DeleteMapping("/assignment-audit/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> deleteAssignmentAudit(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        System.out.println("Delete AssignmentAudit with ID = " + id + "...");

        assignmentAuditRepository.deleteById(id);

        return new ResponseEntity<>("Assignment Audit has been deleted!", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

The mapping of my tables looks like:

[image]

Selection.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="selection")
public class Selection implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long selectionId;

    @Column(name="selection_date")
    private String selectionDate;

    @Column(name="selected_by")
    private String selectedBy;

    @Column(name="pan_exim_number")
    private Long panEximNumber;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name="phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Column(name="selection_type")
    private String selectionType;

    @Column(name="consignment_no")
    private String consignentNo;

    @Column(name="consignment_date")
    private String consignentDate;


    @Column(name="selection_period_from_date")
    private String selectionPeriodFromDate;

    @Column(name="selection_period_to_date")
    private String selectionPeriodToDate;

    @Column(name="agent_no")
    private Long agentNo;

    @Column(name="custom_office")
    private String customOffice;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy="selection")
    private List<AssignmentAudit> assignmentAudit;
//i omitted getters and setters as i have in my program
}
```

AssignmentAudit.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "assignmentaudit")
public class AssignmentAudit implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "auditorGroupId")
    private AuditorGroup auditorGroup;

    @Column(name = "assignmentDate")
    private String assignmentDate;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "selectionId")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Selection selection;
}
```

AuditorGroup.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "auditor_group")
public class AuditorGroup implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long auditorGroupId;

    @Column(name="group_desc")
    private String groupDesc;

    @Column(name="from_date")
    private String fromDate;

    @Column(name="to_date")
    private String toDate;
}
```

AssignmentAuditRepository.java

```
public interface AssignmentAuditRepository extends JpaRepository<AssignmentAudit, Long> {

}
```

I only need to delete `assignmentAudit` by its `id` such that `selection` and `auditGroup` remains unchanged and unaffected when `assignmentAudit` is deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` from the `@ManyToOne` mappings.

Alternatively change it, so that the `CascadeType.DELETE` is not included.

Comment: how can i only neglect cascadetype.delete from all types? i need exact code to change it

Comment: thnk u i changed and worked :) really appreciated ur help